# Angular rangeSlider - update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider, rangeslider

I use rangeSlider for filter according to price. I need to make reset button, to set this slider to its default values.

**My HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-nav-center">
    <div class="middle-filter-slider">
      <input type="text" class="rangeJs" value="" name="range"/></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Initialize slider**

```
function initRangeSlider(min, max) {
  $(".rangeJs").ionRangeSlider({
    hide_min_max: false,
    keyboard: true,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    from: min,
    to: max,
    type: 'double',
    step: 1,
    postfix: " eur",

    onStart: function(data) {},
    onChange: function(data) {},
    onFinish: function(data) {
      $scope.filter.priceFrom = data.from;
      $scope.filter.priceTo = data.to;
      priceFactory.requestPrices(null, null, $scope.filter);
    },
    onUpdate: function(data) {
      $rootScope.slider.reset();
    }
  });

  $rootScope.slider = $(".rangeJs").data("ionRangeSlider");
}
```

**Function for update**

```
$rootScope.slider.update();
```

When I click on update-button, function update is calling. It updates the values, and returns me all items. It´s fine, but problem is that slider(view) doesn´t set to init (default) state.

[image]